# How to prevent list from breaking inside container with column-gap?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container and inside could be any content. The most times there a p-tags but sometimes also some lists.

I kinda have the following code:

```
<div class="content">
    <ul>
        <li>Test LI</li>
        <li>Test LI</li>
        <li>Test LI</li>
        <li>Test LI</li>
        <li>Test LI</li>
        <li>Test LI</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy.</p>
</div>
```

Nu the following happens: The list is being torn apart! Poor list.

[image]

I want the li's to be connected again. I tried the following css, but it didn't work for me so far.

```
.content {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 60px;
    -moz-column-gap: 60px;
    column-gap: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.content ul li {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -moz-page-break-inside:avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Thanks,
Robin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found probably the most simple solution. (facepalm)

```
.products-post-content ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.content ul li`, try this:

```
.content ul {
   margin: 0;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari */
    page-break-inside: avoid;           /* Theoretically FF 20+ */
    break-inside: avoid-column;         /* IE 11 */
    display:table;                      /* Actually FF 20+ */
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lf1ehc0k/)

or using `inline-block` as:

```
.content ul {
   display: inline-block;                   
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lf1ehc0k/1/)